# how to create a custom store method using backpack V4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to create a custom method in backpack version 4 as I had in backpack version 3 but i'm facing an issue when I tried to insert data.

In the upgrade guide

> (https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/upgrade-guide)

was wrote that I can have my custom method but I've to do some steps before, for example:

**Replacing that line:**

use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation

**for this line:**

use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation { store as traitStore; }

**Then, i've created my method:**

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
        Log::debug('testing...');
        $redirect_location = $this->traitStore();
        return $redirect_location;
    }
```

But when I try to carry out the create process, backpack shows an error view

> Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\StoreRequest does not exist

Going back to the previous version (3.6) I saw that requests were renamed for example

```
use App\Http\Requests\ItemRequest as StoreRequest;
```

So, I tried to do the same for backpack version 4, but for this try I got an new error

> Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ItemRequest not found

Can someone support me with this issue? how may I create my custom methods as I had in the previous version (3.6)?

Thank's

Comment: Try using the same name for type-hinting the request, as the name you've given when loading the request at the top of the file. If at the top you have "use xxx/StoreRequest" you should have "public function store(StoreRequest $request)". Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please, try the following:

- Replace back

> use App\Http\Requests\ItemRequest as StoreRequest;

- to

> use App\Http\Requests\ItemRequest;

- In your method, change the parameter from

> public function store(StoreRequest $request)

- to

> public function store(ItemRequest $request)

and now, try to create a new data again

Comment: Worked but in that way will not be possible to have separated requests for (create and update). How does it works when I have different requests for each operations?